# What is the proof that the Expected value of squared sample mean is equal to variance divided by n plus squared mu

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I understand that the expected value of any squared random variable is equal to squared population mean plus population variance - for instance here:

[Where did this statistics formula come from: $E[X^2] = \mu^2 + \sigma^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461307/where-did-this-statistics-formula-come-from-ex2-mu2-sigma2)

This gives me an intuitive understanding that the expected value of squared sample mean is equal to variance/n plus squared mu. However, is there any mathematical proof? preferred is non-calculus one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sums of squares minus square of sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720876/sums-of-squares-minus-square-of-sums)

Comment: [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_as_Expectation_of_Square_minus_Square_of_Expectation) is another online proof, you should easily be able to find more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not necessarily true if the observations $\ X_1,$$\,X_2,$$\,\dots,$$\,X_n\ $ are correlated. Here's a proof for the case when they're pairwise uncorrelated..
\begin{align}
E&\left(\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_\limits{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right)=E\left(\left(\mu+\frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)\right)^2\right)\\
&=E\left(\mu^2+\frac{2\mu}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\sum_\limits{j=1}^n(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)\right)\\
&=\mu^2+0+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\sum_\limits{j=1}^nE\big((X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)\big)\\
&=\mu^2+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\sigma^2\\
&=\mu^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\ .
\end{align}
The pairwise uncorrelatedness of the $\ X_i\ $ and $\ X_j\ $ is used in the proof where $\ E\big((X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)\big)\ $ is set to zero for $\ i\ne j\ $.  Of course, the same identity holds *a fortiori* if $\ X_1,$$\,X_2,$$\,\dots,$$\,X_n\ $ are independent.